# Changing error android admob ads

Tags: android, admob, andengine, ads

I added ads by admob in my game without xml.And I changed colors of ads from admob.com.But It the same theme in my game.How to change theme of admob ads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out AdMob's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/bestpractices#adcolors) for how to set ad color properties in code.

NOTE: Changing the color theme only works for AdMob text ads, and not AdSense backfill text ads.  This [image](http://s18.postimage.org/kgubacw09/Capture.png) you provided is an example of an AdSense backfill ad where the color scheme currently cannot be changed.

Comment: i did it but it still the same.nothing changed

Comment: Forgot to mention that the color scheme changes only work for AdMob frontfill ads.

Comment: So is there any way to change google AdSense backfill color scheme?

Comment: Unfortunately not at this time.

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think that ads are themable ? I don't think people patent color (kodak yellow for instance) to see them modified...

Comment: In my game,It seems like that:http://s18.postimage.org/kgubacw09/Capture.png                  But I want to change to http://s14.postimage.org/aizy22l9t/Capture.png